# Android onLocationChanged not called

Tags: android, locationmanager

What do I need to do to get my LocationListener to fire it's onLocationChanged method?

I am new to this stuff (java and android).  Here is what I am doing.
I handle a request for a location by calling context.startService(serviceIntent);
Inside the intent service i have a nested class to act as the LocationListener
in side the onHandleIntent method i start a thread which requests the location updates
I maintain a reference to the LocationListener object and the tread in the the OnHandleIntent method.

my plan was for the onLocationChanged method to update a variable that i could check periodically to see if the update has been completed, then break out of loop and do something with the location.

The problem is the onLocationChanged method never gets called.
The LocationListener object is still valid right to the end of the onHandleIntent method.
I can even call it directly and get the debug message that I am expecting.
I am pretty sure that the DDMS is changing the location as I have printed it out in various debug logs and i see it changing.

Here is the code:

```
package com.example.locationrequestreceiver;

import android.app.IntentService;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Looper;
import android.util.Log;

public class LocationRequestService extends IntentService    {


    private LocationManager locationManager;

    public class UpdateHandler implements Runnable, LocationListener {

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location arg0) {
            Log.d("myStuff", "inside location changed");
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}
        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}
        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Looper.prepare();
            Log.d("myStuff", "inside thread");
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates("gps", 0, 0, this);
            Log.d("myStuff", "run ending");
            Looper.loop()  //  <--- this was the fix
        }

    }

    public LocationRequestService() {
        super("LocationRequrestService");
        Log.d("myStuff", "inside the service");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent arg0) {
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        UpdateHandler update_handler = new UpdateHandler();
        Thread update_handler_thread = new Thread(update_handler);
        Log.d("myStuff", "starting thread");
        update_handler_thread.start();

        for (int count = 0; count < 20; count++) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }
        }
        Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation("gps");
        update_handler.onLocationChanged(location);
    }




}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The calling thread must have a [Looper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Looper.html). You could use a [HandlerThread](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/HandlerThread.html) instead of a Thread.

Comment: Can you elaborate a little oh how to do that here.  I read the doc and a few things on HandlerThread, but it's not clear how to use it here.

Comment: BTW ... this did give me a hint to call Looper.loop() in my threads run method, but I would like to try to get the HandlerThread to work

Comment: A simpler solution would just be to run the LocationListener on the main UI thread. Location updates are inherently asynchronous and so they won't block your UI thread. Is there any reason why this has to run on a separate thread?

Comment: The request comes from a BroadcastReceiver.  My understanding is a broadcastreceiver may (or does) go away as soon as the onReceive finishes.  So that creates/starts the intentService,  which I original tried to use as the listener but that does not seem to really work either, so i figured I could start a thread that should hang around long enough to receive the update.

Comment: I marked this as answered and added the Looper.loop() statement into my code.  Thanks Ashwin.